# Create a new JS object instance of an existing class dynamically from a DOM input element

Tags: javascript, html, class, object, dom-events

In Javascript for HTML how can I create a new object instance of a class where the object name / variable name of a new object in the class comes from the text value of an input element?

In this example...
I have a class called myClass and I've made one myClass object instance called Chickens with a property ‘myProperty’ with a value of 100. Say I wanted to use the name input element in the browser to make a new myClass object instance such as Dogs and set it's myProperty value to 49 with the property input element.

Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="name" placeholder="name">
        <input id="property" placeholder="property">
        <button id="btn"></button>
    </body>
    <script src="rhythm-class.js"></script>
</html>
```

and

```
function myClass() {
        this.myProperty
}

let chickens = new myClass()

chickens.myProperty = '100'

console.log(chickens)

let currObj = null
let currProp = null

document.querySelector('#name').addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        currObj = e.target.value
        let `${e.target.value}` = new myClass
})
document.querySelector('#property').addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        currentProp = e.target.value
        let `${currentObj}`.testProperty = e.target.value
})
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        console.log(`${currentObj}`.testProperty)
})
```

Comment: dogs.myProperty=document.getElementById("property").value should retrieve a value for you.

Comment: How do I create dogs by typing in dogs in the name input element?

Comment: The most you could do from getting the name input is making a class with a string variable with that value.

Comment: You cannot create variable names dynamically. What you actually want is to put the instances of your class in an object or a `Map`, where you can give each its own name. Don't start with `let dog = new myClass, cat = new myClass;` but rather `const animals = {dog: new myClass, cat: new myClass};`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function myClass(value) {
  this.myProperty = value;
}

let chickens = new myClass("100");

console.log(chickens);

let form = document.querySelector("form");
let inputs = form.elements;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let nameField = inputs["name"];
  let propField = inputs["property"];

  // you can test here if both of the values are set
  window[nameField.value] = new myClass(propField.value);
  console.log(window[nameField.value].myProperty);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input id="name" placeholder="name">
    <input id="property" placeholder="property">
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Since every variable in JS is the property of the global object, we can make use of that here. Note that the global object is the `window`. We set the property name of the global object to our instance name and then instantiate the class passing our input value.

Instead of using the global object, it is recommended you use a local object to store the variable names.

Comment: This seems to do what I want only I used a local array rather than window and it worked!

Comment: I've applied this concept and would like to do something similar with prototypical functions and <select>. New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425201/call-a-function-dynamically-in-js-with-something-dynamic-like-select-value-myf

Comment: If you use local array, you are storing only the result and you wouldn't be able to retrieve that later. So I suggested you to use a local object to map variable names to the result. Anyway, if the answer helped you, you can choose it as accepted answer.